# is there any way to avoid merging a particular set of files to master branch from another branch in git?

Tags: git, github

I have a set of files and it shows as conflicts in my PR in GITHUB.I don't want to show this file as a conflict in my PR and it should not be merged at all to my master branch, even though another branch(PR) has that file modified.

I tried adding `.gitattributes` file with the merge strategy as `merge=ours`, but it still did not work. Below is the `.gitattributes` file i pushed to the repo.

```
#.gitattributes
file.txt merge=ours
```

Is it possible to skip particular files to stop getting merged to master (whatever) branch and not show as conflicts in the PR ?

[image]

Comment: No way, sorry. There're 2 problems. **1.** Merge strategy `merge=ours` works only for conflicts. **2.** `.gitattributes` only works locally; Git hostings ignore it to avoid running unknown code on their servers. So the only solution is: merge locally using `git merge --no-commit`, restore the file: `git checkout HEAD file.txt`, commit the merge and push.